ngx-markdown-editor is not working and not show the right preview
here this is  markdown-editor demo github in here i am not use bootstrap style in angular.json  because in my main project i am using tailwind css so if in angular.json  i am use bootstrap style than it is generate the conflict so in in demo also i am not use bootstrap style and  if i am write the raw content than it is give the perfect answer
like  and the same code i am write in my project than it is give the this type of preview 
here this is code for ts file

    import { LMarkdownEditorModule } from 'ngx-markdown-editor';
import { CategoryService } from './../services/category.service';
import {
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  HostListener,
  Inject,
  Renderer2,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CeateOpenaiService } from './ceate-openai.service';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { ProjectService } from '../services/project.service';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { debounceTime, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { L10nLocale, L10N_LOCALE, L10nTranslationModule } from 'angular-l10n';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { marked } from 'marked';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-openai',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    L10nTranslationModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    LMarkdownEditorModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './create-openai.component.html',
  styleUrl: './create-openai.component.scss',
})
export class CreateOpenaiComponent {
  isDataLoading: boolean = true;
  createform!: FormGroup;
  isNoDataFound: boolean = false;
  transcriptionHistory: string[] = [];
  isSidebarOpen = false;
  dropdownOpen = false;
  lastCreatedAtId: any;
  toggleSidebar() {
    this.isSidebarOpen = !this.isSidebarOpen;
  }

  toggleDropdown() {
    this.dropdownOpen = !this.dropdownOpen;
  }

  private transcriptionSubscription: Subscription | null = null;

  isVisible: boolean = false;
  transcription: string = '';
  aiResponse: string = '';
  isRecording: boolean = false;
  isEditing: boolean = false;
  editedText: string = '';
  aiResponses: string[] = [];
  data: any[] = [];
  projectnames: any[] = [];
  projectname: any;
  paginationMeta: any = {};
  currentPage: number = 1;
  perPage: number = 15;
  projectId: number = 0;
  aiId: any;
  audioBlob: Blob | null = null;
  mediaRecorder: any;
  silenceTimeout: any;
  openAiResponse: string = '';
  spacebarTimer: any;
  minHoldTime = 100;
  isLoading: boolean = false;
  isLoadingSaveData = false;
  isUpdate: boolean = false;
  sortBy: string = '';
  sortDir: string = '';
  aires: boolean = false;
  image: any;
  templateId: number = 0;
  isProcessing = false;
  private typingSubject = new Subject<string>();
  page: number = 0;
  previewContent: string = '';
  aitrancriptId: number = 0;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    public router: Router,
    private openAIService: CeateOpenaiService,
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private CategoryService: CategoryService,
    @Inject(L10N_LOCALE) public lang: L10nLocale
  ) {
    this.route.params.subscribe((result: any) => {
      this.projectId = result.id;
    });
  
  }

  formpromoInitialization() {
    this.createform = this.fb?.group({
      transcription: ['', [Validators.required]],
      airesponse: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  get trancript() {
    return this.createform.get('transcription');
  }

  get airesponse() {
    return this.createform.get('airesponse');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projectId = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;
    this.getprojectname();
    this.updatetranscript();
    this.openAIService.fetchProjectById(this.projectId)
  }
  transcribeAudio() {
    if (this.audioBlob) {
      const audioFile = new File([this.audioBlob], 'recording.wav', {
        type: 'audio/wav',
      });

      this.openAIService.transcribeAudio(audioFile, 'en').subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
          if (response && response.text) {
            this.transcription += ' ' + response.text;
            this.transcriptionHistory.push(this.transcription);
            this.savedata();
          }
          this.isProcessing = false;
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error('Transcription error:', error);
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      );
    }
  }


    
  onTextInput(event: any) {
    this.transcription = event.target.value;
    this.typingSubject.next(this.transcription);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  savedata() {
    if (this.aitrancriptId !== 0) {
      this.saveapi(false);
      return;
    }
    this.templateId = this.CategoryService.getTemplateId() || 0;
    const newEntry = {
      transcript: this.transcription,
      ai_response: '',
      template_id: this.templateId,
      created_at: format(new Date(), 'dd MMM. yyyy HH:mm:ss'),
      isUpdate: false,
    };
    this.isLoadingSaveData = true;
    this.openAIService
      .createqustion(this.transcription, newEntry, this.projectId)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.isLoadingSaveData = false;
          if (response) {
            this.openAIService.addAiResponse({
              ...response.ai_interaction_id,
              isUpdate: false,
            });
            this.aitrancriptId = response.ai_interaction_id.id;
            this.aires = false;
            this.isRecording = false;
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('error', error);
        }
      );
    }

  saveText() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.aires = true;
    this.getAIResponse(this.transcription)
      .then((aiResponseText: string) => {
        this.aiResponse = aiResponseText;
        this.isLoading = false;
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

async getAIResponse(prompt: string): Promise<string> {
  try {
    this.aires = true
    const response = await this.openAIService.getResponse([prompt]);
    this.aiResponse = response;
    this.createform.get('airesponse')?.setValue(this.aiResponse);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error generating AI response:', error);
    return 'Something went wrong while generating the response.';
  }
}

  saveapi(isreset: boolean = true): void {
    this.openAIService
      .getOpenAiResponse(
        this.page,
        this.perPage,
        this.projectId,
        this.sortBy,
        this.sortDir
      )
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        if (response && response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
          this.data = response.data || [];
          const sortedData = this.data.sort(
            (a, b) =>
              new Date(b.created_at).getTime() -
              new Date(a.created_at).getTime()
          );
          this.lastCreatedAtId = sortedData[0]?.id;
          try {
            const template_id = this.CategoryService.getTemplateId();
            const updatedData = {
              transcript: this.transcription,
              ai_response: this.aiResponse,
              template_id: template_id,
              image: this.CategoryService.getImage(),
              created_at: format(new Date(), 'dd MMM. yyyy HH:mm:ss'),
              isUpdate: true,
              id: this.lastCreatedAtId,
            };
            this.isLoadingSaveData = true;
            this.openAIService
              .updateTranscription(
                this.projectId,
                updatedData,
                this.lastCreatedAtId
              )
              .subscribe(
                (response: any) => {
                  this.isLoadingSaveData = false;
                  if (isreset) {
                    this.toastr.success('Data saved successfully!');
                  }
                  this.aiResponse = updatedData.ai_response;
                  this.openAIService.addAiResponse(updatedData);

                  if (response) {
                    if (isreset) {
                      this.createform.reset();
                      this.aitrancriptId = 0;
                      this.aiId = '';
                      this.transcription = '';
                      this.aiResponse = '';
                      this.templateId = 0;
                    }
                    this.aires = false;
                    this.cdr.detectChanges();
                    this.isRecording = false;
                  }
                },
                (HttpErrorResponse) => {
                  this.isLoadingSaveData = false;
                  if (
                    HttpErrorResponse.status === 422 &&
                    HttpErrorResponse.error
                  ) {
                    if (HttpErrorResponse.error.transcript) {
                      this.trancript?.setErrors({
                        serverError: HttpErrorResponse.error.name.join(', '),
                      });
                    }
                    if (HttpErrorResponse.error.description) {
                      this.airesponse?.setErrors({
                        serverError:
                          HttpErrorResponse.error.description.join(', '),
                      });
                    }
                    this.toastr.error('Please fix the form errors.');
                  } else {
                    this.toastr.error(HttpErrorResponse.error.message);
                  }
                }
              );
          } catch (error) {
            this.toastr.error('An unexpected error occurred.');
            this.isLoadingSaveData = false;
          }
        }
      });
   }

  private updatetranscript(): void {
    this.transcriptionSubscription =
      this.openAIService.transcription$.subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.isEditing = true;
        this.transcription = data.transcript;
        this.aiResponse = data.ai_response;
        this.aiId = data.id;
        this.aitrancriptId = data.id;
        this.aires = true;
        this.templateId = data.template.id;
      });
  }

  update(aiResponse: any) {
    if (this.createform.invalid) {
      this.createform.markAllAsTouched();
      return;
    }
    const image = this.image;
    const updatedData = {
      transcript: this.transcription,
      ai_response: aiResponse,
      template_id: this.templateId,
      image: image,
      created_at: format(new Date(), 'dd MMM. yyyy HH:mm:ss'),
      isUpdate: true,
      id: this.aiId,
    };
    this.openAIService.addAiResponse(updatedData);
    this.isLoadingSaveData = true;
    this.openAIService
      .updateTranscription(this.projectId, updatedData, this.aiId)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.isLoadingSaveData = false;
          if (response) {
          }
          this.createform.reset();
           this.transcription = '';
           this.aiResponse ='';
          this.aires = false;
          this.isEditing = false;
          this.aitrancriptId =0;
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
          this.toastr.success(response.message);
        },

        (HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.isLoadingSaveData = false;
          if (HttpErrorResponse.status === 422 && HttpErrorResponse.error) {
            if (HttpErrorResponse.error.transcript) {
              this.trancript?.setErrors({
                serverError: HttpErrorResponse.error.name.join(', '),
              });
            }
            if (HttpErrorResponse.error.description) {
              this.airesponse?.setErrors({
                serverError: HttpErrorResponse.error.description.join(', '),
              });
            }
            this.toastr.error('Please fix the form errors.');
          } else {
            this.toastr.error(HttpErrorResponse.error.message);
          }
        }
      );
  }
  
  getprojectname() {
    this.isDataLoading = true;
    try {
      this.projectService.getProject().subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
          if (response && response.data) {
            const project = response.data.find(
              (item: any) => item.id === this.projectId
            );
            this.projectname = project;
          }
          this.isDataLoading = false;
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error('Error fetching project:', error);
          this.isDataLoading = false;
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.isDataLoading = false;
    }
  }


  preRenderFunc(content: string) {
    return content.replace(/something/g, 'new value');
  }

  postRenderFunc(content: string) {
    this.previewContent = content;
    this.aiResponse = content
    return content.replace(/something/g, 'new value');
  }

  onEditorLoaded(event: any): void {
  }

  onPreviewDomChanged(event: any): void {
    if (event && event.target instanceof HTMLElement) {
      const previewHtmlContent = event.target.innerHTML;
      this.previewContent = previewHtmlContent;
    } else {
    }
  }
}



and here

     <div class="mt-2" *ngIf="aiResponse">
              <!-- <textarea
                [(ngModel)]="aiResponse"
                id="airesponse"
                name="airesponse"
                formControlName="airesponse"
                rows="3"
                [ngClass]="{
                  'border-red-500':
                    createform.get('airesponse')!.invalid &&
                    (createform.get('airesponse')!.dirty ||
                      createform.get('airesponse')!.touched)
                }"
                class="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-2 px-4 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm/6"
              ></textarea> -->
              <!-- <md-editor name="Content"
              [(ngModel)]="aiResponse"
              [preRender]="preRenderFunc"
              [postRender]="postRenderFunc"
              [height]="'300px'"
              formControlName="airesponse"
              (onEditorLoaded)="onEditorLoaded($event)"
              (onPreviewDomChanged)="onPreviewDomChanged($event)"
              required
              maxlength="500"
              [ngClass]="{
                'border-red-500':
                  createform.get('airesponse')!.invalid &&
                  (createform.get('airesponse')!.dirty ||
                    createform.get('airesponse')!.touched)
              }"
              class="block w-full"
              >
              </md-editor> -->
              <md-editor name="Content"
              [preRender]="preRenderFunc"
              [postRender]="postRenderFunc"
              [height]="'200px'"
              (onEditorLoaded)="onEditorLoaded($event)"
              (onPreviewDomChanged)="onPreviewDomChanged($event)"
              required
              maxlength="500">
              <slot custom-btns></slot>
            </md-editor>
              <div
                *ngIf="
                  createform.get('airesponse')!.invalid &&
                  (createform.get('airesponse')!.dirty ||
                    createform.get('airesponse')!.touched)
                "
                class="text-red-500 text-sm mt-1"
              >
                <div *ngIf="createform.get('airesponse')!.errors?.['required']">
                  {{ "Createai.AIRESPONSE_ERROR" | translate : lang.language }}
                </div>
                <div
                  *ngIf="createform.get('airesponse')!.errors?.['serverError']"
                >
                  {{ createform.get('airesponse')!.errors?.['serverError'] }}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


this is html file
